# Create hierarchical python object where arguments to methods are from hierarchy

Tags: python, class, inheritance, module

There is an existing module I use containing a class that has methods with string arguments that take the form:

```
existing_object.existing_method("arg1")
```

or

```
existing_object.existing_method("arg1:arg2")
```

The arguments are in a hierarchical structure.
I would like to create a module that objectifies the arguments and makes them methods of the class of the imported module such that use would look like this:

```
my_object.arg1.my_method()
```

or

```
my_object.arg1.arg2.my_method()
```

my_method() would call existing_method() while passing it the "arg1:arg2" as an argument.

If someone could point me in the right direction to get started I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Both of these are rather strange APIs. I think a hierarchical structure would be handled better with a list of arguments (in the case of linear hierarchies) or with a list of lists. (Also, how would `my_object.arg1.arg2` work in the case of arbitrary arguments, or non-identifier arguments?)

Comment: It would help to see actual examples of arguments.

Comment: Arbitrary arguments aren't allowed. The argument format for the existing method is a non-python hierarchical interface format.
I'd like to let the user move through that hierarchy to select options using the python . structure and then at the end select a simple method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a custom `__getattr__` that returns special method caller instances:

```
class MethodCaller(object):
    def __init__(self, args, parent):
        self.args = args
        self.parent = parent
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return MethodCaller(self.args + (name,), self.parent)
    def my_method(self):
        return self.parent.existing_method(':'.join(self.args))

class MyClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return MethodCaller((name,), self)
    def existing_method(self, arg):
        print arg
```

Example:

```
>>> MyClass().arg1.my_method()
arg1
>>> MyClass().arg1.arg2.my_method()
arg1:arg2
>>> MyClass().foo.bar.my_method()
foo:bar
```

Comment: I think I need to restate this question another way. Will edit the question.

Comment: I may have confused the situation by calling them arguments.
I want the user to be able to tab to see the available options so arg1 and arg2 would have to be attributes of MyClass() as would the my_method.
The arguments don't need to be undefined. I'm happy to define them somewhere.

Comment: Ah. In that case you could store the arguments in e.g. a nested dictionary structure and dynamically add the attributes as you walked down.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this more clearly I realized that what I really wanted was to be able to use the IPython introspection of modules to navigate the hierarchy. This meant that I simply needed to create objects like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def my_method(self.arg)

arg1 = Foo("arg1")
arg1.arg2 = Foo("arg1:arg2")
```